Intersection of decreasing sequence of star-convex sets
A set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is star-convex if there is $z\in A$ such that for all $x ∈ A$, the line segment from $z$ to $x$ lies in $A$. Let $\{A_i : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a decreasing sequence of closed star-convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Must $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ be connected?
If the "closed" hypothesis is dropped, then the following is an example of a decreasing sequence of star-convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i = \{(0,0), (1,0)\}$. Each $A_i$ is the corresponding filled triangle with the lower segment removed: 
A couple of final remarks: the result is true in $\mathbb{R}$ since being star-convex is equivalent to being convex and the intersection of convex sets is convex. On the other hand, if there is a bounded $A_j$, then $\{A_i : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is eventually a decreasing family formed by metric continua and, therefore, $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ is a continuum; in particular, $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ is connected. Therefore, a counterexample to the statement must be formed by star-convex and unbounded sets.

In general, you can get problems with unbounded sets: for example in $\mathbb{R}^2$, if you consider $A_i = \mathbb{R}\times[0,+\infty[\setminus \triangle_{i}$ where $\triangle_i$ is the triangle whose vertices are $(-1,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,i)$, and its sides are not consider in order to $A_i$ would be closed. You can see that $A_i$ is star convex and $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}} A_i$ is not star convex and it is also disconnected.
